# Submitting text and image/video on single form

Tags: html

I am working on social networking site where user can post photo and text on single form submission like facebook wall post.
What should be the form type. Is there any example please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form should have enctype set to "**multipart/form-data**".

Here is an example:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="file" name="video">
    <input type="submit" name="just_a_button">
</form>
```

Of course, you need a proper PHP (or other server-side language) script on your server side to process such form.

Additional restrictions in maximum file size may occur on both browser and server side (PHP environment configuration). So for sending video files I would strongly suggest considering some ready plugins, for jQuery, a Flash uploader or sth., that streams files being sent, part-by-part, instead of sending whole file at once. In general, 30-50 MB or larger files are difficult to send, just via a simple HTML form, due to these restrictions.

Comment: A [W3C Recomendation -- Forms section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) could be a good source on information here, but as with all official W3C documents, it is a really long readout! :]